# Merge "Facebook pages" events results using Graph Api v2.x?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, events, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Sorry for the stupid title.. My goal is to query events from FB pages and merge them into a single result..

Here is Graph Api example:
/events?ids=108346555871750,644726018907878

And this is the result what I want to see with Graph Api (with FQL it is easy!):
SELECT eid FROM event WHERE creator IN (SELECT page_id FROM page WHERE page_id='108346555871750' OR page_id='644726018907878')

The above Graph Api call are two FB pages whose have a few events where both of them is a creator for that event.
For now the result look like this (in the Graph Api):

PAGE1: eventA, eventB(!), eventC, eventD(!), etc.

PAGE2: eventX, eventB(!), eventY, eventD(!), etc.

And this is what I want to see if possible like in the FQL query result:

RESULT: eventA, eventB, eventC, eventD, eventX, eventY, etc.

So everything in the same column for that two pages where the double events appear only ONCE!

Is it even possible in Graph API? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the above by doing a graph call like the one bellow. It uses the latest graph api `2.2`

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/events/?ids=pageId1,pageId2,pageId3,pageId4&fields=id,description,name,start_time,end_time,timezone,location,venue,cover,owner&access_token=YourAccessToken`

.....